# Shifting Levels in Nested Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, nested

I have some data from a remote server in a deeply nested dictionary in Python. Due to the data collection process (which I cannot control), several of the levels of this dictionary get wrapped in an unnecessary dictionary with a single key called `"__collections__"`. For example, the dictionary looks like this

```
{"data_level_1":
    {"__collections__":
        {"data_level_2": ...}
    }
}
```

when really what I would like is

```
{"data_level_1":
    {"data_level_2": ...}
}
```

I need a way to recursively iterate through the nested dictionary to "shift" those wrapped dictionaries one level up while getting rid of the `"__collections__"` wrapper dictionary. Here is my attempt:

```
import collections.abc

def remove_repeat_named_level(dictionary, key):
    q = list(dictionary.items())
    for v, d in q:
        if isinstance(d, MutableMapping):
            for nv, nd in d.items():
                if isinstance(nd, MutableMapping):
                    if v==key:
                        nd = remove_repeat_named_level(nd, key)
                        q.append((nv, nd))
                        if (v, d) in q: q.remove((v, d))
                    elif nv==key:
                        nd = remove_repeat_named_level(nd, key)
                        q.append((v, nd))
                        if (v, d) in q: q.remove((v, d))
                elif v==key:
                    q.append((nv, nd))
                    if (v, d) in q: q.remove((v, d))
    return dict(q)
```

where `dictionary` is the nested dictionary and `key` is the name of the single key in the wrapper dictionaries I want to remove (in this case, `collections`).

This works great on a few simple test cases, for example:

```
test_key = "A"
test_dict = {"A": 
                {"B": 
                    {"A": 
                        {"i": 
                            {"A": 
                                {"One": 
                                    {"A": 
                                        {"alpha": "a", 
                                         "beta": "b"
                                        }
                                    }, 
                                 "Two": 2
                                 }
                             }, 
                         "ii": 2
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }

remove_repeat_named_level(test_dict, test_key)
```

returns the expected result:

```
{'B': {'i': {'One': {'alpha': 'a', 'beta': 'b'}, 'Two': 2}, 'ii': 2}
```

However, when I pass the nested dictionary with my data through the function, the recursion just seems to stop at some level:

Dictionary:

```
test_d2 = {"__collections__":
               {"tasks": 
                  {"task1":
                       {"__collections__":
                          {"subjects":
                              {"subject1":
                                  {"date": 1,
                                   "time": 1,
                                   "__collections__":
                                       {"surveys":
                                           {"survey1":
                                               {"survey_data":
                                                    {"Q1": {"Response": 1},
                                                     "Q2": {"Response": 2}
                                                    }
                                               },
                                                "__collections__": {}
                                           }
                                       }
                                  }
                              }
                          }
                       }
                  }
               }
         }
```

Expected:

```
               {"tasks": 
                    {"task1":
                          {"subjects":
                              {"subject1":
                                  {"date": 1,
                                   "time": 1,
                                   {"surveys":
                                       {"survey1":
                                           {"survey_data":
                                                {"Q1": {"Response": 1},
                                                 "Q2": {"Response": 2}
                                                }
                                           }
                                       }
                                    }
                                  }
                              }
                          }
                    }
               }
```

Result:

```
{"tasks": 
              {"task1":
                  {"subjects":
                      {"subject1":
                          {"date": 1,
                           "time": 1,
                           "__collections__":
                               {"surveys":
                                   {"survey1":
                                       {"survey_data":
                                            {"Q1": {"Response": 1},
                                             "Q2": {"Response": 2}
                                            }
                                       },
                                        "__collections__": {}
                                   }
                               }
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
         }
```

Been wracking my brain for hours trying to figure this out. Why does the recursion just stop at some point? Is there some case I'm not accounting for?

Comment: Your last expected result isn't a valid python dictionary. You can't just have a naked `{"surveys":` in the dict without a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between your small example and your actual data is that in your small example, the bad key is always alone in its dict; whereas in your actual data, the bad key is sometimes mixed in with other keys in a dict.

You can simplify your recursive function a lot:

```py
def remove_repeat_named_level(d, bad_key):
  if not isinstance(d, dict):
    return d
  else:
    new_d = {k: remove_repeat_named_level(v, bad_key) for k,v in d.items() if k != bad_key}
    if bad_key in d:
      new_d.update(remove_repeat_named_level(d[bad_key], bad_key))
    return new_d
```

Testing with your data:

```py
>>> remove_repeat_named_level(test_d2, '__collections__')
{'tasks': {'task1': {'subjects': {'subject1': {'date': 1, 'time': 1, 'surveys': {'survey1': {'survey_data': {'Q1': {'Response': 1}, 'Q2': {'Response': 2}}}}}}}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive generator function:

```
def remove_keys(d):
   if not isinstance(d, dict):
      yield d
   else:
      for a, b in d.items():
         if a == "__collections__":
             yield from remove_keys(b)
         else:
             yield (a, k[0] if len(k:=list(remove_keys(b))) == 1 and not isinstance(k[0], tuple) else dict(k))
```

---

```
import json
r = {'data_level_1': {'__collections__': {'data_level_2': None}}}
test_d2 = {'__collections__': {'tasks': {'task1': {'__collections__': {'subjects': {'subject1': {'date': 1, 'time': 1, '__collections__': {'surveys': {'survey1': {'survey_data': {'Q1': {'Response': 1}, 'Q2': {'Response': 2}}}, '__collections__': {}}}}}}}}}}
print(json.dumps(dict(remove_keys(r)), indent=4))
print(json.dumps(dict(remove_keys(test_d2)), indent=4))
```

Output:

```
{
    "data_level_1": {
        "data_level_2": null
    }
}
```

---

```
{
    "tasks": {
        "task1": {
            "subjects": {
                "subject1": {
                    "date": 1,
                    "time": 1,
                    "surveys": {
                        "survey1": {
                            "survey_data": {
                                "Q1": {
                                    "Response": 1
                                },
                                "Q2": {
                                    "Response": 2
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```